# How to add a header to a single http request rather than to all as default

Tags: c#, http, request, http-headers, httpclient

I have to add a header value for a single request only. all I´ve found was `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Version","1");`
As far as I understood, this would affect all future requests. But I want it for one single request only.

Is there a possibility to do that? I dont want to create a new httpclient just for one request since I have to pass session cookies and so on.

In this particular case, I want to add a referrer.

Best regards and thanks for help

Comment: Well if you call `SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage)` you can put the headers in that...

Comment: Thank you Jon, Can you also give a short statement on _how_ to "put the headers in that..."?

Comment: No, why don't you try it and edit your question with what you've tried instead. Stack Overflow is not an alternative to doing research. Start by finding the documentation for `HttpRequestMessage` and looking for "headers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats my solution which I came up with

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referrer",GlobalVar.baseURI + referrer) ;
string responseString = client.GetStringAsync(GlobalVar.baseURI +loan + "/investment").Result;
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Referrer");
```